# The right limit of a function is infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Any idea how i can show the section of the solution highlighted in green?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Numerator keeps strictly positive while $x$ tends to $0$ (better its limit is $1$).

Denominator is simply $x$ and $x$ approaches to $0$ from right, hence mantainig positivity.

So the limit is of the form $\frac{1}{0^+}$ that is clearly $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that, for any $M>0$, the solution set of
$$
\frac{5x^2+1}{x}>M
$$
contains an interval of the form $(0,\delta)$. We can assume $x>0$ and $M>5$, so the inequality is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
5x^2-Mx+1>0\\
x>0
\end{cases}
The roots of the polynomial are both positive, the least one is
$$
\delta=\frac{M-\sqrt{M^2-20}}{2}
$$
so the interval $(0,\delta)$ is contained in the solution set.